# git - Fetch file from remotes/origin/main to temp area (not a local branch)

Tags: git

I want to be able to do my own compare on a binary file (*.DBF) under git with our own comparison tool using Powershell. That is because the file header can change without the content changing.

"git diff --binary --output=$tempfile $path" does not provide diffs which are useful for this task.

I found a few posts but they seem convoluted in using different branches. "git checkout xx" does not seem to have options to do this.

Is there a git syntax to achieve this?

If i can fetch to a temp area, then i can compare main to the local branch, and if no meaningful changes have occurred, then use "git checkout $path" to undo the changes. Thanks

Comment: Why not configure the program using `.gitattributes` to be the diff driver? See the docs: [1](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes#_defining_an_external_diff_driver), [2](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Attributes#_diffing_binary_files).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `git show` to extract the content of the file to *stdout* (and then send it where you want), so:

```
git show origin/main:path/to/file.dbf > temp.dbf
```

Comment: Thanks!, i will assume that binary files are "shown" unmodified no matter the file file format, ANSI etc.

Comment: I compared the checksum of a binary file on disk with the output from `git show` and it matches, so it seems safe.

Comment: My testing using an exe and a dbf file is i couldn't get a byte for byte copy. I tried using --encoding on the git show and various combinations of | out-File encoding's + -NoNewLine and -width to a large value (as well as the original '>' )  
This works well enough to text files but not binary for me. 
Notepad++ considers an exe to be DOS ANSI and a DBF as Macintosh ANSI.

Comment: Does `git cat-file -p` behave the same for you? Oddly enough, I'm seeing bit-for-bit copies for both `git show` and `git cat-file -p`, using images and compiled binaries as test cases, verified using `sha256sum` on the output.